# How to set different languages for different spiders on a website?

Tags: search-engine, seo, multilingual

I have multilanguage website. Actually, the website language is chosen according to the web browser language.

Is there any way to set the language according to the search engine spider? For example:

- Display the website in Chinese for Baidu search engine spider,
- Display the website in Russian for Yandex spider?

Comment: This is really off topic for Programmers, but I don't think you've explained your problem well enough for us to decide whether it should be migrated to Stack Overflow or Webmasters.

Comment: ya i transfer it stackoverflow ..

Comment: @user44570: Don't worry, the moderators can automatically migrate it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [crawler identification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Crawler_identification). When a request is made to your website, [`User-Agent` field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) contains the information about the browser or the crawler.

Depending on the crawler, the value of this field will be different. You can then associate different values with different languages. You can also take a look at the [large list of user agents](http://www.user-agents.org/).

---

I'm still pretty sure that by doing this, **you'll lower your rank in search engines** since you provide different responses to crawlers than to real users, but I don't have solid references to support this statement.

In all cases, crawlers are expected to gather resources in different languages, and **those crawlers know how to deal with multilingual websites**, except maybe the ones which try to follow every worst practice. Also, **the search engines you quoted are not limited to one language**. Yandex is available for example in [Turkish](http://www.yandex.com.tr/). As for Baidu, [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baidu), it serves China, Japan, Thailand, Egypt and India.

Comment: thanks for info :)  i think i should stick with english language but for users loading different languages is i think good and will have no effect on search engine ranking